# not exit a bash script when one of the sub-script fails

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am new to shell script. I have a script that runs several test scripts using different input files. Currently it exits if any one of the input test fails. I want the test to complete running the loop and exits with all errors accumulated at last.

## main.sh

```
set -e ;
set -x ;
for f in $files;do
    ./scripts/test_script.sh $f
done
```

======================

## test_script.sh : runs few stuff and exits like this.

```
:
:
:
exit $?
```

================

Comment: `for f in $files` is buggy in and of itself. You can't work with an arbitrary filename list that way; filenames that contain spaces, newlines, glob characters, etc. will all misbehave. Lists of arbitrary names should be stored in an **array**, not a string.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are correct. 

but In my specific case, I won't have spaces, newlines etc in filename. I have bunch of tests that is named test_*.sh and I am just finding it and storing in $files. 
files=$(find ./mypath -name 'test_*.sh')

Comment: Understood. To write code that works right when things don't behave like you expect, though, it's safer to use `readarray -d '' files < <(find ./mypath -name 'test_*.sh' -print0)`, and then `for file in "${files[@]}"; do ...` (that's bash 4 syntax; for compatibility with older versions a formulation that doesn't fit as well in a comment is needed).

Comment: ...eh, it doesn't fit all that badly. The compatible-with-older-bash version is `files=(); while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do files+=( "$file" ); done < <(find ... -print0)`, and then usage the same way, `for file in "${files[@]}"; do ...` -- though you could also just put the code that handles each file directly in the `while` loop and not use any `for` loop at all. [Using Find](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) goes into more details, whereas [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) discusses the original practice.

Comment: @HarshKumar : I don't understand why you deliberately use a `set -e`  and then complain about exactly the behaviour you have requested, but if you want to keep this setting (perhaps because you will add later other statements, where to exit on error is desired, you can for example write the invocaition of your script as `scripts/test_script.sh $f || true`, and the loop will not be aborted. Of course the exit code will get lost too in this case. You need to specify in your question, whether you want to communicate a non-zero exit code to the caller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set -e` is what causes your script to exit immediately after a failed command. Get rid of it.

If you want the exit status to be 1 if any test fails, try out the following:

```
exit_status=0

for f in $files; do
  if ! ./scripts/test_script.sh "$f"; then
    exit_status=1
  fi
done

exit "$exit_status"
```

The value of `exit_status` will only be changed from 0 to 1 if an invocation of `test_script.sh` has a non-zero exit status.

---

Update: you can collect the failed scripts in an array (which you should also be using to store the list of files):

```
files=(foo.txt bar.txt)
failed=()

for f in "${files[@]}"; do
  ./scripts/test_script.sh "$f" || failed+=("$f")
done

if (( ${#failed[@]} != 0 )); then
  echo "Failed:"
  printf '  %s\n' "${failed[@]}"
  exit 1
else
  exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Or `./scripts/test_script.sh "$f" || exit_status=1`

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to accumulate the names of the scripts that failed and then output the list of failed scripts at the end.

Comment: About the update:
Since now you don't return 

exit "$exit_status" 

at the end, will main.sh exit with status 0 or non-zero? I want main.sh to finally return with exit 1 if any of the test fails.

Comment: Updated; a none-empty array is synonymous with an exit status of 1.

Comment: Thank you so much. Accepted this as solution.

Comment: I would need to use set -e in main.sh as I have many other logic that I would like to exit immediately if failed. 

However  when I use the updated code above, I want to unset e before 
 ```files=(foo.txt bar.txt)```
and later set it again after the update snippet above. is it possible?

Comment: In other words, I intent to do something like this. Is it possible?

```
set -e

***some code ****

unset -e

***some more code***

set -e
```

Comment: `set +e` undoes `set -e`. However, [using `set -e` is a bad idea in general](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105); better to use `|| exit` on individual commands where you want a nonzero exit status to be fatal. (Skip past the parable to the exercises if you're in a hurry).

Comment: Thanks. 
I asked a new question thinking I had marked this question accepted. Would you like to answer there so that I will mark that also as accepted. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62185918/how-to-set-and-unset-variable-multiple-times-in-a-shell-script

Thank you again for your help.